# How do I avoid unwanted users create accounts?

Tags: 7, users

I am using Drupal 7 and use the [User verification](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_verify) module for blocking (prohibiting) unwanted users in our site, but a user is creating an account every second.

How can I stop that from happening?

Is it possible to first send an email to the users, with a verification link  included? When that link is clicked, users will be registered on the site.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this link https://www.drupal.org/node/877404 has lot of discussions which might help you.

Comment: is it possible,that user firstly got a mail with verification link.. when he click on this link then user will be register on drupal site.. otherwise not register.

Comment: Are you looking for this ? https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_invite

Comment: something like this... But I need to approve by user not admin... who is registering on site.

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding either of those modules (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot)

> Honeypot uses both the honeypot and timestamp methods of deterring spam bots from completing forms on a Drupal site. These methods are effective against many spam bots, and are not as intrusive as CAPTCHAs or other methods which punish the user.

- [Anti Spam by CleanTalk](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleantalk)

> Invisible antispam without CAPTCHA, questions, puzzles, counting animals, math and etc. Just install and forget.
>
> CleanTalk is a SaaS spam protection service for Web-sites.
>
> CleanTalk uses protection methods which are invisible for site visitors.
> Using CleanTalk eliminates needs in CAPTCHA, questions and answers, and other methods of protection, complicating the exchange of information on the site.

- [BOTCHA Spam Prevention](https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha)

> BOTCHA Spam Prevention is a highly configurable non-CAPTCHA spam protection framework.
>
> BOTCHA, doesn't abuse human users, BOTCHA protection is completely
> transparent to them and non-intrusive.

If these modules still don't help to reduce your issues, then I would go for plan-b, i.e:

- consider reviewing (extending if needed) your registration form, by adding 1 (or more) field(s) so that it becomes AbitMORE difficult to complete registration requests. Either some obvious question for which your target audience should know the answer by heart, or something for which the answer can be found by first browsing around on your site. Yet another option is to ask some question about their real name or address, which may help later on how "serious" the request is.
- make admin approval required for every new user registration request. This will reduce the speed of "registered" users to the speed of an admin approving / reviewing such requests.

Pretty sure this plan-b will help a lot ... up to you to decide if it fits with "the entire point of your site".

Comment: Upvoting this as the best answer; yes you can prevent bots from using your site with email confirmation and such but preventing bots from creating (unactivated) accounts in the first place should be the prior goal.

Comment: @NicklasMandrupFrederiksen merci for the feedback (and +1) ...!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of control over user accounts you want.  By default Drupal allows visitors to register new accounts.  If you want to disable that, you can set *Who can register accounts?* to *Administrators only* at `/admin/config/people/accounts`.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom module and check user ip if this ip user already register in or already they can create account set restriction on using this function

```
function user_login_authenticate_validate($form, &$form_state) {
/**********/
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7

or using this module 
https://www.drupal.org/project/ip

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to first send an email to the users, with a verification link included? When that link is clicked, users will be registered on the site.

Yes, go to admin/config/people/accounts, and select "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account."